# ffmpeg can loop png but not audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following to stream an image to YouTube:

```
ffmpeg -threads:v 2 -threads:a 8 -filter_threads 2 -thread_queue_size 1080 \
-loop 1 -re -i ./image.png \
-i ./track.mp3 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -qp:v 19 -profile:v high -rc:v cbr_ld_hq -level:v 4.2 -r:v 60 -g:v 120 -bf:v 3 -refs:v 16 -preset fast -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx
```

And the looping for the image (to keep it streaming over) works, but not the sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that FFmpeg input options are applied *per input*. So, `-loop 1` is only specified for `-i image.png` input, and `-i ./track.mp3` has no input options defined. Now, to loop audio track, you need to use `-stream_loop` input option like this:

```
ffmpeg -threads:v 2 -threads:a 8 -filter_threads 2 -thread_queue_size 1080 \
-loop 1 -re -i ./image.png \
-stream_loop -1 -i ./track.mp3 \
 ...
```

Comment: I found another workaround, as I got another issue of the image not updating, but I marked the answer as correct for anyone else.